# PHP mail function strange behaviour

Tags: php, email

I hosted my web in ipage web hosting. I want to make my web send an automatic email reply after filling a form, but the email is not working. I use a simple mail function like this:

```
mail($to,$mail_subject,$mail_content, null, '-f'.$from);
```

The strange thing is, if I use a dummy email addres for $from (I use webmaster@web.com) and use only single line $mail content, it worked. If I use the original email address from and the mail content from variable I set with PHP, it doesn't work. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Why not use `"From: $from"` in the `headers` argument?

Comment: I have tried that, but it didn't work. I googled the problem and found out using -f is useful. I found out it is working now but the problem came from another place now.

Answer (score 0):

`To send email using php mail() function from Ipage and some other hosting provider like "bigrock","1&1" you have to use a email Id of your own domain either in the sender/receiver list.`

I am using the php mail function `mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);` It is working fine in iPage hosting.

Comment: What do you mean with email Id of my own domain? I use the $from address using my domain is not working and it is only work if I use that dummy email address. That's why I'm confused now.

Comment: If your domain name which is hosted in iPage is " yourdomain.com" then use one email Id (Not necessary to create,But advisable to create an email Id) dont-reply@yourdomain.com (Or any Email Id). Use that email id either in $from or use in $to(as one recipient).

Comment: I tried PHPMailer library using SMTP provided by ipage server. It said message sent but I never receive my email. How should I check this?